# elasticsearch: how to get only documents whose normalized scores (_score divided by max_score) are above certain threshold

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

While querying, I am trying to get only documents whose normalized scores(`_score` divided by `max_score`) are above a certain threshold. Is there any way to do that? I tried using function score, but I am getting a `SearchPhaseExecutionException`.

My query using the sense plugin:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
      "min_score": 0.4,

      "function_score" : {
         "query" :{
            "query_string": { "_all": "test"}
         },
         "functions": [
         {
            "script_score": {
                "script": "return _score / max_score;"
            }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

> Exception trace: "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong. The "min_score" field should be outside the query block. And the syntax of "query_string" is also wrong. [Refer doc](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

Try this:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "min_score": 0.4,
    "query": {
      "function_score" : {
         "query" :{
            "query_string": {
                "query": "test",
                "fields": [
                    "_all"
                ]
            }
         },
         "functions": [
         {
            "script_score": {
                "script": "return _score / max_score;"
            }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

Moreover the error trace should be containing information about the failure. Generally you should be able to identify/get a direction for the errors from there.